# How to add aliases in SharePoint rest query?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-rest-api, odata

I need a REST query to get field values in a SharePoint list. Internal name of the List is People and it has Id, Title, ShortName and Age columns. So REST Query is

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('People')/items?select = Id,Title,ShortName,Age
```

There is a requirement to get ShortName as Name. Is there any equivalent Alias to query like

```
ShortName as Name
```

So full query is looks like,

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('People')/items?select = Id,Title,ShortName as Name,Age
```

Applying name after retrieval is not an option. I need a "REST" solution and need to know whether this is capable or not with just a REST Query.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `Domain\username` in your Spreadsheet column, you need to create  **single line text column** column called `UserName` and assign the `=Me` value in Calculated Value text box. This column will give you the alias name of the user who is entering the item in list.

Then, Create calculated column named as `DomainUser`. In this column, you need to concatenate your Domain with `Loggedin` User name instead of work `email id`. Ex: `US\username`.

**Code**

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: "/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items",
type: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    var dataResults = data.d.results;
    var resultId = dataResults[0].AuthorId.results[0];        
    getUser(resultId)
},
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(xhr));
}
});

function getUser(id){
var returnValue;
jQuery.ajax({
url: "http://YourSite/_api/Web/GetUserById(" + id + ")",
type: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
success: function(data) {
       var dataResults = data.d;
  //get login name  
  var loginName  = dataResults.LoginName.split('|')[1];
  alert(loginName);     
  //get display name
  alert(dataResults.Title);
}
});
}
```

Refer: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692289/How-to-Get-Login-Name-and-Display-Name-using-Sha

Comment: Is there any "REST" solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft there is not rest endpoint for using alias $select

For your reference you look at the endpoints offered

[Microsoft reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests)